# PostgreSQL Select highest value within time period

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Using Rails, I'm trying to perform a SQL command to return an array of rows that contain the highest value for a certain user per day.

For example:

```
  user_id(integer) |        created_at(datetime)    | score(integer)
-------------------+--------------------------------+---------------
              1    |      "2015-07-27 21:35:24"     |         100
              1    |      "2015-07-27 21:35:24"     |         123
              2    |      "2015-07-27 21:35:24"     |         101
              2    |      "2015-07-27 21:35:24"     |         122
              3    |      "2015-07-27 21:35:24"     |         103
              3    |      "2015-07-27 21:35:24"     |         115
              1    |      "2015-07-26 21:35:24"     |         116
              1    |      "2015-07-26 21:35:24"     |         151
              2    |      "2015-07-26 21:35:24"     |         122
              2    |      "2015-07-26 21:35:24"     |         134
              3    |      "2015-07-26 21:35:24"     |         123
              3    |      "2015-07-26 21:35:24"     |         111
              1    |      "2015-07-25 21:35:24"     |         129
              1    |      "2015-07-25 21:35:24"     |         152
              2    |      "2015-07-25 21:35:24"     |         120
              2    |      "2015-07-25 21:35:24"     |         109
              3    |      "2015-07-25 21:35:24"     |         142
              3    |      "2015-07-25 21:35:24"     |         131
```

Expected results:

```
  user_id(integer) |        created_at(datetime)    | score(integer)
-------------------+--------------------------------+---------------
              1    |      "2015-07-27 21:35:24"     |         123
              2    |      "2015-07-27 21:35:24"     |         122
              3    |      "2015-07-27 21:35:24"     |         115
              1    |      "2015-07-26 21:35:24"     |         151
              2    |      "2015-07-26 21:35:24"     |         134
              3    |      "2015-07-26 21:35:24"     |         123
              1    |      "2015-07-25 21:35:24"     |         152
              2    |      "2015-07-25 21:35:24"     |         120
              3    |      "2015-07-25 21:35:24"     |         142
```

I've been combining various joins, `having`, and other methods, but to no avail. I can't get it to filter the results. I've made a little bit of progress by `select`ing max values per day, but then I can't filter out the lower ones on a per `user_id` basis. I managed to do it using multiple `group_by` and `map` in Rails, but it's super slow since it has to re-iterate over the entire array, and since there is a lot of records, it can take some time.

EDIT:

My solution was as follows:

```
    all_scores_in_time_period = UserScore
      .where("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) = ?", Date::MONTHNAMES.index(params[:month_control]))
      .where("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) = ?", params[:year_control])
      .select("DISTINCT ON(DATE(created_at), user_id) *")
      .order("DATE(created_at) desc")
```

This first filters by month/year, and then returns a list of users by their top score per user per day.

Comment: '21:35:24' for all days prevents thorough testing of solutions (because it effectively converts timestamp just to date), please, provide more real life timestamps.

Comment: @Dzenly - The times were not necessary. It was to be filtered by `date` anyway, not date times. I included the times to try to be more explicit, but you're right- it does confuse the main point a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `distinct on ()` which is a Postgres extension to the `distinct` operator:

```
select distinct on (user_id, created_at) user_id, created_at, score
from the_table
order by user_id, created_at, score desc;
```

If you want solution using standard SQL, this can also be achieved using window functions:

```
select user_id, created_at, score
from (
  select user_id, created_at, score, 
         row_number() over (partition by user_id, created_at order by score desc) as rn
  from the_table
) as t
order by user_id, created_at;
```

The solution with `distinct on()` is typically faster in Postgres.

With a window function you could also handle ties: when a user has the same (highest) score more than once on a day. The solution with `row_number()` will only return a single row per (user_id, created_at). If you want all rows with the same (highest) score, you need to use `dense_rank()` instead.

**Edit**

If you want to ignore the time part of the timestamp column, just cast it to a date:

```
created_at::date
```

Comment: `distinct on` is what I've been looking for. Thank you!